# get selected value of a woocommerce_form_field select

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have some custom field with type of select in my product page,I should get values to set them as order options,so I need help for getting user selected option 
thx for your help :)

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'day_event', array(
            'type'     => 'select',
            'required' => true,
            'class'    => array( 'wps-drop' ),
            'label'    => __( 'Event day' ),
            'options'  => $GLOBALS['first_selection'],
            'id'       => 'first_field_selector'

        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this brother

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'day_event', array(
            'type'     => 'select',
            'required' => true,
            'class'    => array( 'wps-drop' ),
            'label'    => __( 'Event day' ),
            'options'  => $GLOBALS['first_selection'],
            'id'       => 'first_field_selector'
    ), $checkout->get_value('day_event') );
```